# How to handle App Signing and uploading to PlayStore for a startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing

I am aware of how the process goes but I am unsure how to approach it when uploading for some other people. I was hired to make an app and to help them get it on the play store, when I sign it, what is the usual approach to the key and the password/ aliases? Are there any guidelines that people usually follow when making them eg length of the password, name of the alias and so on? Should I give them the key as well, where is the key usually stored?

Comment: you should go through documentation for App signing. Since you are developing app for someone else, make sure to share the key with all the details with them. This key will be used for future updates on the same app.https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ Yes I've read it several times, I am mostly referring to practices and real-world examples

Answer (score 0):

The keys are stored in a keystore. Make sure to create a new keystore and there create a key called "key0" (my IDE shows this as the standart name IDK). Make sure to give them the keystore name & password, as well as the "key0" and its password.

Then, you can simply give them the keystore file. Make sure to tell them to back it up.
When they want to make a new release, they will browse to the keystore that you gave them and will be able to sign the new release with the passwords and keyname you gave them.